# Do rollback wars on deleted posts generate auto-flags?

Tags: discussion, rollback-wars, auto-flags

It isn't clear if this is the case from [the post on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75906/put-an-end-to-rollback-wars/222644#222644); perhaps I should ask there, but there's a few other questions to this besides the title question.

If this isn't done, *shouldn't it be done?*  There is of course a particular question which is prompting this question; here on Meta, there appears to be a rollback war on a deleted post, where the OP in question had previously entered into the war while the post was not in a deleted state.  I *believe* it is happening because I had followed the post before it was deleted, and said war is appearing in my mailbox, even after the deletion.  I can't tell who is rollbacking who, but the notifications are there regardless.  I am aware I can unfollow it.

Back to the point, I'd assume that even though the disruption is hidden, that it's still disruption of a sort, so shouldn't there be an auto flag there if there isn't one already?

Perhaps further, should rollbacking a deleted post even be possible?  I'm sure there's probably reasons one can, but I cannot immediately think of many other solutions.  I understand that users can of course be suspended.

Comment: The post is mod deleted so unless the OP puts the post into a state where a mod is prepared to undelete it it's kind of pointless for the OP to roll it back. The OP just has to learn that.

Comment: Rolling back a deleted post is just a special case of *editing* a deleted post, which should probably continue to be allowed, even in the case of a mod-deletion.

Comment: I'm more worried about the things that can still be seen (which shouldn't be seen).

Comment: I don't think rollbacks on deleted posts should generate flags.  Rollback wars on undeleted posts are important because it shows up publicly, but if someone wants to spam the rollback button on a deleted post, they're more than welcome to.  It's probably a pretty good stress reliever.